# Dockerizing client and server into separate containers with Node serving SSR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, express, vite

I'm currently preparing my project for deployment and trying to dockerize client and server into separate containers for better scalability. The project uses Vite, Node, React and I have implemented SSR from Node serving it.

The problem is that I don't know how to import my `entry-server.cjs` file into Node and use its default and only function render to create a layout of the page.

Help would be appreciated a lot.

### server/index.ts

```
let render: (url: string) => string
 
...

  if (isProd) {
    // without docker it was like this
    render =  (await import(resolve("../client/dist/entry-server.cjs"))).render
  }
}

app.use('*', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.originalUrl
    const appHtml = render(url)

    if (!isProd) {
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)
    }

    const html = template.replace(`<!--ssr-->`, appHtml)

    res.status(200).set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }).end(html)
  } catch (e) {
    !isProd && vite.ssrFixStacktrace(e as Error)
  }
})
```

### client/src/entry-server.tsx

```
export default function render(url: string | Partial<Location>) {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={url}>
            <App />
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
}
```

I tried importing dynamically and using http module, but had no luck.